# When does the browser decide to wrap a flexbox container?

Tags: css

In the following code, will the browser decide whether to wrap the `#container` element into new lines based on whether the initial sizes exceed the width of the cross axis or the main axis?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#container div {
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I read in an answer that the container will wrap elements in newlines if the total size of the items exceeds the width of the cross axis, but I thought it would only be if it exceeds the main axis. So I wanted to know if I was wrong or the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `flex` items, they will always depend on the **main axis** space to decide where to break into new line.

The main axis can be **horizontal** (default) or **vertical**, depend on [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Here is an example, items will break into **new row** when the total **width** of items in the current row exceeds `600px`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}

#container div {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

If you change `flex-direction` to `column`, now the main axis becomes **vertical**, and `flex-basis` now defines the initial **height** of the items (instead of width).

And if the total height of items in the current column exceeds `600px`, items will break into **new column**

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
}

#container div {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```